# Pull-request "linter"

Tags: objective-c, ruby, continuous-integration, lint

I had seen a tool a while ago that would let me define rules for GitHub pull-requests, and could be enforced during CI.

The rules could be for instance:

- The commit title should respect a format
- The number of files changed cannot be higher than 10
- There should be no stray ":focus" in the specs
- etc.

I can't remember the name of this tool.

Comment: Any Github-integrated CI will do this. For example. check this: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/.travis.yml and this: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/Rakefile

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to remember the tool that among other things does "verify that commit messages match CONTRIBUTING.md requirements" but with a DSL, not having to write your own commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the tool I was looking for: it's called [Danger](https://github.com/danger/danger):

> ## What is Danger?
>
> Danger runs after your CI, automating your team's conventions
>   surrounding code review.
>
> This provides another logical step in your process, through this
>   Danger can help lint your rote tasks in daily code review.
>
> You can use Danger to codify your teams norms, leaving humans to think
>   about harder problems.
>
> ## For example?
>
> You can:
>
> - Enforce CHANGELOGs Enforce links to Trello/JIRA in PR/MR bodies
> - Enforce using descriptive labels Look out for common anti-patterns
> - Highlight interesting build artifacts Give specific files extra focus
> - Danger provides the glue to let you build out the rules specific to    your team's culture, offering useful metadata and a comprehensive
>     plugin system to share common issues.

Answer (score 1):

HoundCI by thoughtbot is a pretty popular tool. It is SaaS-based and free to use for open source projects: https://houndci.com/

It supports `ruby` and `javascript`.

Comment: thanks! it seems to be limited to code checking. the tool I had in mind was also applying to the PR, commit messages themselves if I remember correctly.